# Is there a way to check if Type<t> inherits from interface then use t.InterfaceMethod()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a few classes and some have inherited from a certain interface. Is there a way I can use the interface method from that class after checking if it first inherits from that interface

this is the base class

```
public class Item 
{
    public string id;
    public string prefabID;
    public string title;
    public string description;
}
```

this is a derived class

```
public class InteractableObject : Item, IEffectReceiver
{
    protected List<Stats> stats = new List<Stats>();
    protected HashSet<Effects> currentEffects;
    public List<Effects.EffectType> effectedBy = new List<Effects.EffectType>();
    public GameObject destroyedPrefab;
    private bool destructible = true;
    private bool destroyed = false;
```

this is the interface

```
public interface IEffectReceiver 
{
    void CheckEffect(Effects effect);   
}
```

I have an ItemContainer class that holds the items and as the base class does not inherit from IEffectReceiver can I do something along the lines of

```
if(Item i is IEffectReceiver)
{
    i.CheckEffect()
}
```

I would rather avoid having Item inherit from IEffectReceiver if I can help it so if there are any workarounds you can throw my way that would be awesome.

Comment: That's the way I would do it. Checking if instances implement certain interfaces is ok in many cases. Of course, you have to write `if(Item i is IEffectReceiver r) { r.CheckEffect() }`

Comment: Yeah I was hoping that would work but CheckEffect() is not a valid method when I try to use it like that

Comment: you will need to add new cast object before calling i.CheckEffect(). Like IEffectReceiver casted= i as IEffectReceiver; Then call casted.CheckEffect();.

Comment: You can. You're calling `CheckEffect()` on the wrong type. You're calling it on the `Item`. Look at my code. I named the `IEffectReceiver` - `r` - it is the correct type.

Comment: @DNakevski No. No cast required. Just use `r`.

Comment: oh you're right alexander. sorry I didn't read that comment properly the first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# provides syntactic sugar to get an `IEffectReceiver` if the type in fact inherits from it, like so:

```
if(Item i is IEffectReceiver effectReceiver)
{
    effectReceiver.CheckEffect(_effect);
}
```